# Java - how to listen to zoom events from touch pad mouse

Tags: java, pinchzoom, touchpad

Using my ThinkPad touch pad, I can zoom in and out on various applications with a pinch gesture, just as I do with other zoom methods, such as Ctrl+Mouse Wheel.

Is it possible to listen to such gestures in java, and dispatch a zoom event to my application?

Answer (score 0):

will this help?

[SmoothPinchZoom](https://github.com/killoctal/AndEngineControls/blob/master/src/com/killoctal/andenginecontrols/camera/SmoothPinchZoom.java)

Comment: Thanks for trying but... I don't see how it will.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - although there's no detail of what kind of component you are considering, for a javafx webview this should work:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ZoomEvent.html

```
webView.addEventFilter(ZoomEvent.ZOOM, (ZoomEvent e) -> {
    double zoom = e.getZoomFactor();
    webView.setZoom(webView.getZoom() * zoom);
    e.consume();
});
```